# Detect handle change inside componentDidUpdate method - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that contains several questions. Some of the questions contains a group of subquestions.

The logic to render sub questions is written inside componentDidUpdate method.

```
  componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState, snapshot) => {
    if (prevProps !== this.props) {
      let questions = this.props.moduleDetails.questions,
          sgq       = {};

      Object.keys(questions).map((qId) => {
        sgq[qId] = (this.state.groupedQuestions[qId]) ? this.state.groupedQuestions[qId] : [];
        let answerId = this.props.formValues[qId],
            questionObj = questions[qId],
            groupedQuestions = [];
        if(questionObj.has_grouped_questions == 1 && answerId != null && (this.state.groupedQuestions != null)) {
          groupedQuestions = questions[qId].question_group[answerId];


          let loopCount = this.getLoopCount(groupedQuestions);

            for(let i=0; i<loopCount; i++) {
              sgq[qId].push(groupedQuestions);
            }
        }
      });

      this.setState({groupedQuestions: sgq});
    }
  }
```

The problem is that on every key stroke of text field, handleChange method is invoked which will ultimately invoke componentDidUpdate method. So the same question groups gets rendered on every key stroke.

I need a way to detect if the method componentDidUpdate was invoked due to the key press(handleChange) event so that i can write logic as follows.

```
if(!handleChangeEvent) {
    Logic to render question group
}
```

Any idea on how to integrate this will be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you should be using `componentWillReceiveProps`

Answer (score 1):

I assume your textfield is a controlled component, meaning that its value exists in the state. If this is the case, you could compare the previous value of your textfield to the new one. If the value is different, you know the user entered something. If they are equal however, the user did something else at which point you want your snippet to actually execute.

Basically:

```
componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) => {
  // if value of textfield didn't change:
  if (prevProps.textfieldValue === this.props.textfieldValue) {
    // your code here
  }
}
```

Another approach is to use `componentDidReceiveProps()`. There you can compare the props to the previous ones, similarly to the above, and execute your code accordingly. Which method is most suitable depends on how your app works.